# Please, please modify the serial downvoting script so that it does not give rep back to the perps

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, serial-voting

I was hit today, 7 downvotes on my answers within one minute.  I've outed a lot of vamps/deadbeats lately and I don't expect that this wil be the last such incident:(

OK, unlike the 'usual' where I get a couple downvotes a day for a week, these arrived all at once and so, at, whenever, I'll get the votes back courtesy of the script.

It is, however, intensely annoying that the script merely reveses the downvote actions. The perp will get back the rep it spent on revenge.

Please stop giving the perps their rep back! They don't deserve it.

Before tonight would be nice, (no this is not an URGENT! request, so don't hit me for that;).

UPDATE: I got 4 more 'simultaneous' downvotes, so -22 for today:(

Comment: I like it but let me play devils advocate.  Imagine: A user who does not know about serial voting sees another user posting bad content.  They then decide to go through all of that users recent post and vote up or down depending if they like it.  Now that is serial voting and the user was not trying to do anything malicious.  Do we want them to lose the rep they spent trying to make the site better?

Comment: @NathanOliver That actually [did happen on Security.SE](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/2220/why-were-my-1s-turned-into-1s), not too long ago.

Comment: Hah @S.L. that title . . . "why-were-my-1s-turned-into-1s"

Comment: This is a fairly ridiculous proposal.  SE has a long-standing policy that mistakes that are easy correctable should not have long-term consequences.  Frankly, why you are still spending your free time at SO is getting to be a big mystery.  We have not heard anything positive from you in a long time and the constant complaining is getting old.  Your very negative attitude is triggering equally negative behavior on other SO users and that is neither their fault nor something they are directly responsible for.

Comment: @NathanOliver sure, that could happen.  They would have to go some, though, to assess 7 questions in under a minute and decide to downvote them all.

Comment: @HansPassant I have never serially downvoted anyone, so 'equally negative behavior' is a stretch, to say the least.

Comment: @MartinJames I would hope the script does not rely on a simple time limit.  If I got 10 votes from the same person in a UTC day I would hope the script would catch it.  I don't know if any of the devs will say or not since the algo is secret.

Comment: @NathanOliver sure.  I'm confident that it wil be reversed just fine.  The shorter the time interval, the lower the chance that it's merely some user reviewing my answers.  The absence of ANY upvotes is also somewhat 'strange' for an an answer review  - surely one must have been worth an upvote.

Answer (score 5):

## Serial Downvote script works fine

> It is, however, intensely annoying that the script merely reveses the downvote actions. The perp will get back the rep it spent on revenge.
>   Please stop giving the perps their rep back! They don't deserve it.

To my experience these users are low rep users so I do not think it's a good idea to take away any reputation they have. If the user(s) keep doing this kind of destructive action that is mentioned, I do trust the moderators to contact that person and/or follow up.

> Before tonight would be nice, (no this is not an URGENT! request, so don't hit me for that;).

I do not think these things happen so fast, moderators work as hard as they can and I'm sure they will also find time to look at this case.

> UPDATE: I got 4 more 'simultaneous' downvotes, so -22 for today:(

You mentioned that you would get your rep back from the script, then this should not be a problem, as it will be returned to you eventually?

Comment: Well, they're already spent the rep on the serial downvoting, so I assume they can happily do without it.

Comment: I don't like a system that punishes people that make mistakes.